# Is there any difference between Toolbar->setOnMenuItemClickListener() and onOptionsItemSelected()?

Tags: android, menu, android-toolbar

Is there any functional wise/performance wise difference between these two approaches?
Should I prefer using one over another?

Answer (score 0):

The only different between them is that `onOptionItemSelected()` is a direct method from the Activity class which gives you direct access to the selected MenuItem. On the other hand, `setOnMenuItemClickListener()` is a method that allows you to register probably a custom listener that will be notified whenever one of the MenuItem is clicked, and the listener must implement the interface `Toolbar.onMenuItemClickListener()`.